# Receiving data from uart in micropython

Tags: uart, micropython

I am trying to receive data from a uart port in MicroPython. I am using a wind gauge that sends a wind read once every second. I need to read that data every second. I created a while loop to read the data, however it is hit and miss. when there is not any data the uart returns "none". So for example I need to get 10 wind readings in 10 seconds.

```
 if start_reading:
    t0 = 0
    while t0 < 1:
        t0 = t0 + .1
        print(t0)
        #print(time.time() - t0)
        data = ser_gauge.readline()
        #print(data)
        if ser_gauge.any() != 'none':
            command = data
```

Comment: It's unclear to me what the problem is. What are you expecting to happen? What is actually happening?

Comment: I want to be able to get the data from the WindGauge once every second. Later on in the code I get the average wind rating from the 10 readings that I take.The wind gauge sends a wind reading once every second. So that when I loop I want to be able to get The value of all 10 readings. But what appears is the word none over and over again randomly the actual wind reading will appear.I have sent the loop to multiple different values to no success.